# Updating a column based on a condition being met in another column

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to create a new column in my data frame. Here is what I want to do:

- Create a new 'star power' column

  - 'star power' increases by 1 point if players amount of hits is in top 5, 2 points if in in 3, and 3 points if player is number 1.

Below is code to create a smaller version of the data frame I am working with:

```
import pandas as pd

mydict = {
'Name' : ['Bill', 'Tom', 'Jack', 'Bob', 'Phil', 'Tim', 'Vick', 'Peter', 'Al', 'Jay'],
'Hits' : [20, 15, 22, 12, 5, 6, 12, 23, 13, 25],
'AVG' : [.750, .500, .250, .300, .200, .760, .450, .400, .330, .500],
'StarPower' : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],}


df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)

df
```

> ```
>     Name    Hits AVG    StarPower
> 0   Bill    20  0.75    0
> 1    Tom    15  0.50    0
> 2   Jack    22  0.25    0
> 3    Bob    12  0.30    0
> 4   Phil     5  0.20    0
> 5    Tim     6  0.76    0
> 6   Vick    12  0.45    0
> 7  Peter    23  0.40    0
> 8     Al    13  0.33    0
> 9    Jay    25  0.50    0
> ```

I know I should use some combination of for loops and if statement. But honestly, I can't wrap my head around it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you add expected ouput? If top1 got 3 points or 3 + 2 +1 points?

Answer (score 0):

First sorting values and then set values by compare them by positions in [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
#if no duplicates
s = df['Hits'].sort_values(ascending=False)
#if possible duplicates
#s = df['Hits'].drop_duplicates().sort_values(ascending=False)

m1 = df['Hits'].eq(s.iloc[0])
m2 = df['Hits'].eq(s.iloc[1:3])
m3 = df['Hits'].eq(s.iloc[4:6])
df['StarPower'] = np.select([m1, m2, m3], [3,2,1])
print (df)
    Name  Hits   AVG  StarPower
0   Bill    20  0.75          0
1    Tom    15  0.50          1
2   Jack    22  0.25          2
3    Bob    12  0.30          0
4   Phil     5  0.20          0
5    Tim     6  0.76          0
6   Vick    12  0.45          0
7  Peter    23  0.40          2
8     Al    13  0.33          1
9    Jay    25  0.50          3
```

If need sum values:

```
#if no duplicates
s = df['Hits'].sort_values(ascending=False)
#if possible duplicates
#s = df['Hits'].drop_duplicates().sort_values(ascending=False)

m1 = df['Hits'].eq(s.iloc[0])
m2 = df['Hits'].eq(s.iloc[:3])
m3 = df['Hits'].eq(s.iloc[:6])
df['StarPower'] = m1 * 3 + m2 * 2 + m3 * 1
print (df)
    Name  Hits   AVG  StarPower
0   Bill    20  0.75          1
1    Tom    15  0.50          1
2   Jack    22  0.25          3
3    Bob    12  0.30          0
4   Phil     5  0.20          0
5    Tim     6  0.76          0
6   Vick    12  0.45          0
7  Peter    23  0.40          3
8     Al    13  0.33          1
9    Jay    25  0.50          6
```

Comment: This worked for me. I tried it with the AVG column and it worked as well. However, it the 'StarPower' column's values that we calculated for hits with replaced with the values calculated when I ran it for AVG. I know one work around is to name the Hits star power column 'StarPower' then name the column which calculates AVG 'StarPower2', then add the two columns together like df['StarPower'] = df['StarPower'] + df['StarPower2']. This seems like a long way to go about doing it though.

Comment: @p.habermanm - Is possible edit your question with solution with `df['StarPower'] = df['StarPower'] + df['StarPower2']` for see if exist some improvement? Because now not sure if understand what need. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pd.Series.rank](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html) with [df.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) or you can also use [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) or [np.select](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

```
df['Rank'] = df['Hits'].rank(method='dense').astype(int)

def fun(x):
    res = 0
    if x['Rank'] == 1:
        res =  3
    elif x['Rank'] <= 3 and x['Rank'] > 1:
        res = 2
    else:
        res = 1
    return res + x['StarPower']

df['StarPower'] = df.apply(fun, axis=1)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
    Name  Hits   AVG  StarPower  Rank
0   Bill    20  0.75          1     6
1    Tom    15  0.50          1     5
2   Jack    22  0.25          1     7
3    Bob    12  0.30          2     3
4   Phil     5  0.20          3     1
5    Tim     6  0.76          2     2
6   Vick    12  0.45          2     3
7  Peter    23  0.40          1     8
8     Al    13  0.33          1     4
9    Jay    25  0.50          1     9
```